# Store old value then send email if value changes

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I had originally posted a question about sending an email if a value in a cell changes, which was solved, but this post looks at storing the old value, so I created a new post as it is a new question.

My goal is to store the old value from a cell within a range of cells, and then based on a Name in another cell if the old value <> new value of the cell in that range an email is sent out stating the value has changed.

Below is the code I have set up based on other posts found in this forum and adjusted to suit my needs, of course it doesnt work, so I am asking for more guidance and assistance.

1. The first `IF` looks to see if the name was changed and if it was
   sends out the email.
2. the second part looks at the name of the person in column C and if
   information changes in a cell in column O it sends out another
   email.

Code:

```
Dim laTargetVal
Dim clsDateTargetval

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim RgSel As Range, RgCell As Range
    Dim lAmountCell As Range, lAmountSel As Range
    Dim OutlookApp As Object, MItem As Object
    Dim Subj As String, EmailAddr As String, Recipient As String
    Dim CustName As String, TitleCo As String, ClsDate As String, ContractPrice As String, lAmount As String, Product As String, Msg As String, pEmail As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Set RgCell = Range("C2:C100")
    Set RgSel = Intersect(Target, RgCell)
    Set lAmountCell = Range("O:O")

    On Error Resume Next

    If Not RgSel Is Nothing Then
        Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        For Each cell In RgSel
            If cell.Value = "Zack" Then
                If laTargetVal <> Target Then
                    Set MItem = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)
                    pEmail = "[email address]"
                    CustName = cell.Offset(0, -1).Value
                    lAmount = Format(cell.Offset(0, 12).Value, "Currency")
                    ClsDate = cell.Offset(0, 5).Value
                    ContractPrice = Format(cell.Offset(0, 10).Value, "Currency")
                    Product = cell.Offset(0, 13).Value
                    TitleCo = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
                    Subj = "***LOAN TERMS CHANGED***" & " - " & UCase(CustName)
                    Recipient = "Zack"
                    EmailAddr = pEmail

                    '   Compose Message
                    Msg = "Hi " & Recipient & "," & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
                    Msg = Msg & "The following loan parameters have changed for " & CustName & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
                    Msg = Msg & "     Product:  " & Product & vbCrLf
                    Msg = Msg & "     Loan Amount changed from:  " & laTargetVal & " to " & lAmount & vbCrLf
                    Msg = Msg & "     Closing Date:  " & ClsDate & vbCrLf
                    Msg = Msg & "     Title Company:  " & TitleCo & vbCrLf
                    Msg = Msg & "     Contract Price:  " & ContractPrice & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
                    Msg = Msg & "Please review the information in their customer folder in the L: Drive." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
                    Msg = Msg & "The Boss" & vbCrLf
                    Msg = Msg & "Vice President"

                    '   Create Mail Item and send
                    With MItem
                        .To = EmailAddr
                        .Subject = Subj
                        .Body = Msg
                        .Send
                    End With
                End If
            End If
        Next cell
    End If

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim lAmountCell As Range, lAmountSel As Range
    Dim clsDateCell As Range, clsDateSel As Range

    Set lAmountCell = Range("O:O")
    Set lAmountSel = Intersect(Target, lAmountCell)
    Set clsDateCell = Range("H:H")
    Set clsDateSel = Intersect(Target, clsDateCell)

    If Not lAmountSel Is Nothing Then
        laTargetVal = Format(Target, "Currency")
    End If
    If Not clsDateSel Is Nothing Then
        clsDateTargetval = Target
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What is that On Error Resume Next hiding? Comment it out and see if any other bugs to deal with

Comment: And what is your specific question?

Comment: I commented out the `On Error Resume Next` and no errors occured, but I did notice that on the `IF` that sends out an email when a cell in Column O changes it only works if the Name in Column C changes as well.

Comment: Can you strip out lots of this code to reduce it to enough to reproduce the problem? It's a little overwhelming, to me, at present.

Comment: My question is:  Is there a cleaner way to write the code to store the old value of a cell in Column O and when it changes send out an email with the old value and the new value based on the name in coluumn C.

Comment: I striped out the code that doesnt apply and left the code i am trying to figure out.  I hope this edit helps.

Comment: Right now, your code looks like it's comparing the Name value to the hard-coded vale of `Zack`. I'm thinking you want that to actually compare to the variable?

Comment: @Mistella I want the code to look through each cell in Column C to see if "Zack" is the name in Column C and then If it is look to see if any of the values in Column O have changed.  Im relatively new to VBA, so im trying to explain the best I can.  Thank you for being patient.

Comment: @Mistella   I think I am just going to scrap the code I am using and try to find even more examples of what I am trying to do, so I can provide cleaner code.  Thank you for your time.